# Servicenow Wiki and Servicenow Community

Tags: servicenow

I want to trigger a specific notification that will contain catalog variable item details on how to do this in servicenow.

Answer (score 1):

Make an email script and call that email script in your notification.
Please follow the below steps:

1. Create an email script:
   [image: Email Script]
2. Create notification and call that email script in the notification.
   [image: Notification]

After the email is a trigger and user click the link that you have made in notification "Catalog item" will open.
Regards,

PKG

Answer (score 0):

You can add `${variables.[variable]}` in a notification's body and it will replace it with the variable you need to get.

You can also do this with a mail script, but I don't recommend that unless the mail script is going to be used in more than one email or the variable needs special formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle the related business logic with a Flow Designer Flow on your Catalog Item, you can use Action: **Get Catalog Variables**, and then use a **Send Email Action** to compose the email.

The variables and its values will be available due to the Get Catalog Variables action, use the data picker to include the data in the email.

Documentation:

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/sandiego-application-development/page/administer/flow-designer/reference/get-cat-variables-flow-designer.html

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/sandiego-application-development/page/administer/flow-designer/reference/send-email-flow-designer.html